# `illegal cyclic reference` error in Eclipse / Scala plugin

Tags: scala

I have created a folder `x` with a source file `package.scala` in it.
The file contains the following code:

```
package x

package object y
{
  trait A

  case class B extends A
}
```

Eclipse displays a compilation error: `illegal cyclic reference involving object y`.

I am not quite sure what this means. If I try to define a normal class (removing `case`) the error message disappears. Another solution is to use a normal object instead of a package object:

```
package x

object y
{
  trait A

  case class B extends A
}
```

Where is the cyclic reference? And how can I remove it? As far as I understand I cannot define a trait and a case subclass of it inside a package object. But I have not clue as to where this restriction comes from.

Comment: I also experienced this issue, compiling the `package object` version with SBT works fine. So, it's an Eclipse bug.

Comment: @pedrofurla: Ok. Then I just need to wait until the bug gets fixed. At least I know that my code is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PedroFuria says this is a bug, but it's always good to look at [the issue associated with the bug](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000503#/activity/ticket:) in these situations. Specifically the conclusion was back in September 2011:

*Defining classes in package objects is only half-working in the Scala compiler itself. You can work around this by defining your class in the right directory. I doubt this will be fully supported any time soon.*

So best to refer to this [related issue](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270003/why-are-classes-inside-scala-package-objects-dispreferred&ei=ax3pUuKoIYSV0QXaxYGACg&usg=AFQjCNFHGiRyw_DiB0kWvZrG54DNsRYH7w&sig2=SM1DiHdUQfWsacFS9csaDw) which points out is easy to replace:

```
package object mypkg {
  class MyClass
}
```

with the following:

```
package mypkg {
  class MyClass
}
```

Which will work with Eclipse / EclipseIDE.