# Why are classes inside Scala package objects dispreferred?

Tags: class, scala, object, package, deprecated

Starting with 2.10, `-Xlint` complains about classes defined inside of package objects. But why? Defining a class inside a package object should be exactly equivalent to defining the classes inside of a separate package with the same name, except a lot more convenient.

In my opinion, one of the serious design flaws in Scala is the inability to put anything other than a class-like entity (e.g. variable declarations, function definitions) at top level of a file. Instead, you're forced to put them into a separate ''package object'' (often in `package.scala`), separate from the rest of the code that they belong with and violating a basic programming rule which is that conceptually related code should be physically related as well. I don't see any reason why Scala can't conceptually allow anything at top level that it allows at lower levels, and anything non-class-like automatically gets placed into the package object, so that users never have to worry about it.

For example, in my case I have a `util` package, and under it I have a number of subpackages (`util.io`, `util.text`, `util.time`, `util.os`, `util.math`, `util.distances`, etc.) that group heterogeneous collections of functions, classes and sometimes variables that are semantically related. I currently store all the various functions, classes, etc. in a `package object` sitting in a file called `io.scala` or `text.scala` or whatever, in the `util` directory. This works great and it's very convenient because of the way functions and classes can be mixed, e.g. I can do something like:

```
package object math {
  // Coordinates on a sphere

  case class SphereCoord(lat: Double, long: Double) { ... }

  // great-circle distance between two points
  def spheredist(a: SphereCoord, b: SphereCoord) = ...

  // Area of rectangle running along latitude/longitude lines
  def rectArea(topleft: SphereCoord, botright: SphereCoord) = ...

  // ...
  // ...

  // Exact-decimal functions
  class DecimalInexactError extends Exception

  // Format floating point value in decimal, error if can't do exactly
  formatDecimalExactly(val num: Double) = ...

  // ...
  // ...
}
```

Without this, I would have to split the code up inconveniently according to fun vs. class rather than by semantics. The alternative, I suppose, is to put them in a normal object -- kind of defeating the purpose of having package objects in the first place.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> But why? Defining a class inside a package object should be exactly equivalent to defining the classes inside of a separate package with the same name,

Precisely. The semantics are (currently) the same, so if you favor defining a class inside a package object, there should be a good reason. But the reality is that there is at least one good reason no to (keep reading).

> except a lot more convenient

How is that more convenient?
If you are doing this:

```
package object mypkg {
  class MyClass
}
```

You can just as well do the following:

```
package mypkg {
  class MyClass
}
```

You'll even save a few characters in the process :)

Now, a good and concrete reason not to go overboard with package objects is that while packages are *open*, *package objects* are **not**.
A common scenario would be to have your code dispatched among several projects, with each project defining classes in the same package. No problem here.
On the other hand, a package object is (like any object) closed (as the spec puts it "There can be only one package object per package"). In other words, 
you will only be able to define a package object in **one** of your projects. 
If you attempt to define a package object for the same package in two distinct projects, bad things will happen, as you will effectively end up with two
distinct versions of the same JVM class (n our case you would end up with two "mypkg.class" files). 
Depending on the cases you might end up with the compiler complaining that it cannot find something that you defined in the first version of your package object, 
or get a "bad symbolic reference" error, or potentially even a runtime error. This is a general limitation of package objects, so you have to be aware of it.
In the case of defining classes inside a package object, the solution is simple: don't do it (given that you won't gain anything substantial compared to just defining the class as a top level).
For type aliase, vals and vars, we don't have such a luxuary, so in this case it is a matter of weighing whether the syntactic convenience (compared to defining them in an object) is worth it, and then take care not to define duplicate package objects.

Comment: you've misunderstood my complaint. If I have a utility package with both classes and functions, then either (a) I have to segregate the classes and functions, the former in a package, the latter in a package object of the same name, or I put them together in a package object, which is "deprecated". The problem with segregating is that it makes it impossible to keep related packages and functions together.

Comment: Although package objects are not open, their corresponding package still is.   I use package objects a lot (they mimmic modules in other programming languages) and have yet to encounter _any_ of the problems you describe.

Comment: Of course they are open, the whole point of my answer is that package objects are closed, while package are open. Good for you that you did not encounter any of the problems I mentioned, but those are not made up issues, I did encounter them. Sure enough, if you tend to put all your code in a single project, or have a distinct package per project (which admittedly is quite common), then you're not going to have much problem with package objects. Also, I'm not advocating against package objects, they clearly have their use, just be aware of the gotchas, and use them only when needed.

Comment: >>How is that more convenient?
It's more convenient, because I don't need to come up with a new name for a separate file

Comment: You can put that in the very same file you'd have put your package object. 
And if you really need a package object (say for type aliases), nothing is stopping you from putting *both* 
the package object and the package scope (where you'd put your classes) in the same file.

Comment: A good practice to solve package duplication is using `com.mycompany.project1` and `com.mycompany.project2` as root package in different project.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a good answer to why this semantically equivalent operation would generate a lint warning.  Methinks this is a lint bug.  The only thing that I have found that **must not** be placed inside a package object (vs inside a plain package) is an object that implements `main` (or `extends App`).

Note that -Xlint also complains about implicit classes declared inside package objects, even though they cannot be declared at package scope. (See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html for the rules on implicit classes.)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a trick that allows for all the benefits of package objects without the complaints about deprecation. In place of

```
package object foo {
  ...
}
```

you can do

```
protected class FooPackage {
  ...
}

package object foo extends FooPackage { }
```

Works the same but no complaint. Clear sign that the complaint itself is bogus.

Comment: No, clear sign of nothing else than the fact that the compiler has limits and cannot catch everything. This says nothing about the validity of the warning in the first place. A warning is just that: the compiler telling you **may** run in problems when doing something (and here you sure can; have you properly read my answer?).