# Declaring two classes in the same compilation unit

Tags: scala, class

I'm pretty new to Scala and would like to ask about conventions. I have the following classes:

```
case class Cltn(msgs: Seq[Msg])
case class Msg(value: Int)
```

Is it common to define this classes in the same compilation unit? Or this is not conventional and we should define them in different ones? I came from Java that's why I ask about this.

If we can define them in the same compilation unit, can we choose the name of this unit that differs from `Cltn` and `Msg`, or this is not conventional? Like `Parameters.scala`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping multiple (case) classes per files in idiomatic in Scala. It's also very common to have them extend a common `sealed trait`, in which case everything will *have to* be defined together.

As for naming conventions, I've seen two different approaches used regularly:

- Name the file with the name of most important class in contains (CamelCase)
- Use a lower case name of the logical concept grouping these things together.

In your case, it looks like the second option would fit better, I would go for `parameters.scala`!

Comment: Btw, what about putting them in a package-object? Is it convetional?

Comment: Package-object should be avoided as mush as possible.

Comment: Why? Whats wrong with that? Can you expand for a little bit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270003/why-are-classes-inside-scala-package-objects-dispreferred